# How to allow my friends to join my Risk of Rain match?

Tags: risk-of-rain

How do I allow my friends to join my Risk of Rain game so we can play co-op. I followed this [tutorial](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=193316279#173113). Is there anyway I can fix it?

EDIT:
It would say Failed to Connect for my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into similiar problems trying to host a server, and it seems to be a common problem. I finally manage to get hosting and joining to work after I opened the proper ports *and* disabled Windows Firewall. I'd suggest turning off your firewall, windows or otherwise, and see if that solves the problem. This may not be the ideal solution, but it's the only solution I could get working.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against disabling your firewall completely. You can do this for a very short time to test if the firewall is the problem, but keeping it off for a longer time is a serious security risk.